# How should I return paginated records from mock json-server which is (json-server)?

Tags: json, typescript, react-redux, json-server

I want to return a page with JSON server which is (https://github.com/typicode/json-server)
Currently, JSON Structure is looking like:

```
records :[
{
id: '2',
name: 'k',
},
{
id:'3',
name:'j'
}
]
```

I am able to return the records with pagination as GET /records?_page=1&_limit=10. After which I have changed the structure of JSON into:-

```
items:{
pageCount: 3,
records :[
{
id: '2',
name: 'k',
},
{
id:'3',
name:'j'
}
]
}
```

Now I want to do GET `/records?_page=1&_limit=10` where I expect to return page 1 with 10 records and `PageCount` along with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you follow closely the [JSON server documentation](https://github.com/typicode/json-server#paginate), it says you can use the `Link` header from the response where you get `first`, `prev`, `next` and `last` links.